# Menu design in CSS & Wordpress: Indent items but highlight whole row

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

It's been a very long time since I've done any HTML/CSS work, but I've volunteered to help a local school rebuild its website in WordPress. Bits of knowledge long-dormant have been coming back to me, but I'm stuck trying to re-create this menu design:

[image]

This is on the left-hand side of the screen.

Wordpress creates the items as a UL, with a nested UL for the child items. I've hacked this to insert a red HR between each item. The relevant CSS so far is:

(for the column containing the menu)

```
#column-left {
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    background: #f4d2d4;
    height: 100%;
}
```

(for the outer UL of the menu)

```
#menu-list{
    padding-top: 36px;
    padding-left: 34px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

(for the links in the menu)

```
#menu-list a {
    font-size: 16pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c61f26; 
}
```

(for the child items)

```
.children {
    padding-left: 37px;
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
}
```

(for the current page highlighting)

```
li.current_page_item a {
    background-color: #c61f26;
    color: white !important; 
}
```

The HTML wordpress currently generates looks like this:

```
<ul id="menu-list">
        <li class="page_item page-item-5 current_page_item"><a href="http://development.newbridge.bathnes.sch.uk/"><hr class="hr-red"/>Home</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-13"><a href="http://development.newbridge.bathnes.sch.uk/news/"><hr class="hr-red"/>News</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-16"><a href="http://development.newbridge.bathnes.sch.uk/school-information/"><hr class="hr-red"/>School Information</a>
<ul class='children'>
    <li class="page_item page-item-20"><a href="http://development.newbridge.bathnes.sch.uk/school-information/calendar/"><hr class="hr-red"/>Calendar</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have various problems with this setup, and I'm not sure how to overcome them. Suggestions gratefully recieved.

1) The background color of the column does not extend all the way down the page, but is only large enough to cover the menu items.

2) The child items are coming up in red text, not black.

3) The HRs between child items are indented to the same depth as the child item text, and not to the same depth as a the parent item text.

4) The red background for the highlighted text only covers the word, not the whole row. This is the biggest headache as I'm not sure how I can keep the padding and still get the highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Astraldiva/pJ3Sv/2/) showing your example. It uses first-child and last-child pseudo classes to set the correct borders. Remove the hr tag, you really don't need that. Use borders instead.

Here is the html I used for the demo (added few list items):

```
<div id="column-left">
    <ul id="menu-list">
        <li class="page_item page-item-5 "><a href="http://development.newbridge.bathnes.sch.uk/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-13 current_page_item"><a href="http://development.newbridge.bathnes.sch.uk/news/">News</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-16"><a href="http://development.newbridge.bathnes.sch.uk/school-information/">School Information</a>
            <ul class='children'>
                <li class="page_item page-item-20"><a href="http://development.newbridge.bathnes.sch.uk/school-information/calendar/">Calendar</a>  </li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-20"><a href="http://development.newbridge.bathnes.sch.uk/school-information/calendar/">Calendar</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-20"><a href="http://development.newbridge.bathnes.sch.uk/school-information/calendar/">Calendar</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-16"><a href="http://development.newbridge.bathnes.sch.uk/school-information/">School Information</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#column-left {
width: 240px;
float: left;
background: #f4d2d4;
padding-top: 20px;
}

#menu-list{
list-style: none;
}


#menu-list li {
padding-left: 20px;
}

#menu-list li:first-child a {
border-top: 2px solid #c61f26;
border-bottom: none;
}

#menu-list a {
border-bottom: 2px solid #c61f26;
display:block;
height: 100%;
font-size: 16pt;
text-decoration: none;
color: #c61f26;
padding: 5px 0;

}

#menu-list li ul.children {
list-style: none;
color: black;
padding: 0;
}

#menu-list li ul.children li {
list-style: none;
padding: 0; 
}

#menu-list li ul.children li a {
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
color: #000;
text-indent: 30px;
}

#menu-list li ul.children li:first-child a{
border-top: none;
}

#menu-list li ul.children li:last-child a{
border-bottom: 2px solid #c61f26;
}

li.current_page_item {
background-color: #c61f26;
border: none;    
}

li.current_page_item a {
color: white !important; 
}
```

Hope it helps.
​
    ​

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Needs a bit of tweaking to get it working properly with the dynamic menu, but I can take it from here. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. If you need something else feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

We can create the nav menu with image by simply add class to that menu .

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]